# Auto search and populate fields using Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a product registration form which I set up through Gravity forms.

What I want to do is import a list of products and product codes into my wordpress installation and somehow link this to my form so that when the user types in the product code into the 'Product Code' section it will then populate the field next to it with the product description.

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this?

The 2 fields I want to use are below...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gravity Forms Populate Anything can easily handle this. Create a custom table or use a second form to enter your data. Then use Populate Anything to query that data via a point-and-click interface. Easy peasy.

http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/